# How to import npm module with scoped name installed from github?

Tags: node.js, npm, javascript

I'm trying to install a fork of a github project with npm (at master rather than any specific commit since I want to develop against it):

```
% npm install parkan/graffiti-mongoose
@risingstack/graffiti-mongoose@2.0.0 node_modules/@risingstack/graffiti-mongoose
```

This appears to look up the parent repo and install it versioned against master on my gh, so far so good. Note that the package uses [scoped package name semantics](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/scoped-packages), which I think is a part of the problem.

```
% npm list |grep mongoose
├── @risingstack/graffiti-mongoose@2.0.0 (git://github.com/parkan/graffiti-mongoose.git#01a8480fa7d787a4d74bf3bcb257d01b4d73129a)
% ls node_modules/@risingstack/graffiti-mongoose
CHANGELOG.md    LICENSE     fixture
CONTRIBUTING.md README.md   package.json
```

However, I can't get node to import or require it in any obvious way:

```
> require('graffiti-mongoose');
Error: Cannot find module 'graffiti-mongoose'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at repl:3:1
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:54:17)
    at _eval (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel/lib/_babel-node.js:86:26)
    at REPLServer.replEval (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel/lib/_babel-node.js:169:14)
    at bound (domain.js:250:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:263:12)
> require('@risingstack/graffiti-mongoose');
Error: Cannot find module '@risingstack/graffiti-mongoose'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at repl:3:1
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:54:17)
    at _eval (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel/lib/_babel-node.js:86:26)
    at REPLServer.replEval (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel/lib/_babel-node.js:169:14)
    at bound (domain.js:250:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:263:12)
> require('risingstack/graffiti-mongoose');
Error: Cannot find module 'risingstack/graffiti-mongoose'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at repl:3:1
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:54:17)
    at _eval (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel/lib/_babel-node.js:86:26)
    at REPLServer.replEval (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel/lib/_babel-node.js:169:14)
    at bound (domain.js:250:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:263:12)
```

How do I require a package that's inside a subdirectory like this?

Comment: The issue appears to be that the parent package is a scoped name: `@risingstack/graffiti-mongoose`

Comment: I have pretty fresh `npm/node:
% npm --version     
3.3.4
% node --version
v4.1.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in npm. Checking out the repo and installing from local filesystem works fine.

Issue filed: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9798

EDIT: this appears to be a limitation of installing from github in cases where artifacts aren't checked in and a prepublish script must run before the module is usable, see https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3055

Answer (score -1):

I added to my package.json:

```
    "some_github_package": "git+https://github.com/user_name/package_name.git",
```

Then run npm install and you'll get it

Comment: Hi Meir, I'm not having trouble with `npm install`, rather with importing the package once it's installed -- take a look at the body of my question.

Comment: got you. Not sure about the naming, but I don't see any index.js file.
Have a look at the structure of a lib I forked and used: https://github.com/meiriko/winston-pushbullet.
My index file says: module.exports = require('./lib/winston-pushbullet');

Comment: The index.js is in `src`, you can see that from package.json. However, there seems to be a bug that causes a bunch of files not to be installed, see my answer below.